# Javascript getUserMedia set FOCUS. What alternatives are there to control camera focus?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, camera, getusermedia

Good afternoon!
Just I describe what I've read quite a huge amount of literature, before asking a question. Unfortunately, the normal solution not founded.

There is a project written in Javascript. Used getUsermedia for video capture and subsequent processing.

Necessary:
1. Set focus camera
2. Understand how i can get value this focus. I need some orientation scale to compare with the same value of focus two images. For example, for human, this value is be the diameter of the pupil of the eye.

It seems now the decision on js does not exist, because it is in the development stage for the third year =(. Most likely, it is necessary to consider a hybrid variant and packaging application for iOS / Android (perhaps with the help of FoneGap).

I will describe some of the features:
1. Packaged based on chromium with use (or partial) html5
2. I would like to minimally depend on the characteristics of the development under devices.
3. If necessary, can use sockets for a bunch of two-part application (html/js, part of the under iOS / Android)

I would be grateful for any ideas / articles
Thank you!

Comment: did you find any solution? I'm seeking how to take pictures with all the possible focuses, but no luck :(